# Link_to doens't work with a link of attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a table with several attributes, one of those attributes is a field wich contents the facebook links.

I'm showing this link in table like that:

```
<% @hr_curriculum_interns.each do |hr_curriculum_intern| %>
  ...
  <td><%= hr_curriculum_intern.facebook %></td>
  ...
<% end %>
```

But now, I want show only a icon instead the link, so, I search and I dont found. I tried do this with many ways, like that:

```
 <td><%= link_to image_tag('icons/facebook.png', {:alt=>"Alt title", :title => hr_curriculum_intern.facebook}), :href=> hr_curriculum_intern.facebook %></td>
```

But, they doesn't work, when I click in link, I'm not direct for facebook page's.

What I'm doing wrong?

Ps: Please, sorry for my english, I hope you can to understand

Update

That way worked for me:

```
  <%= link_to (image_tag('icons/linkedin.png', :width => "20", :height => "20")), "http://#{hr_curriculum_generic.facebook}" %>
```

Thanks a lot for help =]

Comment: Syntax of link to helper is: `link_to "text", "{link}"`
Try this

`<td><%= link_to image_tag('icons/facebook.png', {:alt=>"Alt title", :title => hr_curriculum_intern.facebook}), hr_curriculum_intern.facebook %></td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this one

```
<%= link_to (image_tag('icons/facebook.png', {:alt=>"Alt title", :title => hr_curriculum_intern.facebook})), hr_curriculum_intern.facebook %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [link_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) with a block

```
<td>
  <%= link_to hr_curriculum_intern.facebook do %>
    <%= image_tag('icons/facebook.png', {:alt=>"Alt title",
                                         :title => hr_curriculum_intern.facebook})
    %>
  <% end %>
</td>
```